# couldn't sign in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Visual studio sign in -
When sign in steps at the end of the process it shows this error  "Your browser is not supported or up-to-date. Try updating it, or else download and install the latest version of Microsoft Edge." I reinstall it and change the default browser too. but no any changes

I reinstalled edge and changed the default browser from Edge to chrome, and updated the Edge also. Need to fixed this error "Your browser is not supported or up-to-date. Try updating it, or else download and install the latest version of Microsoft Edge."